# Why does this custom formatter work for individual resources but not the collection?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I'm creating a proof of concept for a collection of microservices and, at the moment, I'm working on content negotiation.

I found a series of posts by [Jeremy Likness](https://blog.jeremylikness.com/5-rest-api-designs-in-dot-net-core-1-29a8527e999c) and started checking out his [demo](https://github.com/JeremyLikness/PASS-2017/tree/master/04-REST-Fundamentals/Slide10-TodoApi-CSV) showing content negotiation with a custom formatter.

I cloned the project from GitHub and ran the project. When I send requests from Postman and Insomnia, except for one use case, I get the expected results. The issue is I cannot get a CSV-formatted response for a collection.

With each request, I add the `accept` header and the appropriate value (`text/csv`, `text/xml`, `text/json`).

When requesting a single resource (`http://localhost:5000/api/todo/1`), the response is formatted as CSV using the custom formatter. This is the expected behavior. However, when requesting a collection (`http://localhost:5000/api/todo`), the response is formatted as JSON.

What am I missing? What am I doing to get CSV for a single resource but JSON for the collection? Requests containing `accept: text/xml` and `accept: text/json` return the content as specified in the accept header. This is just an issue with `text/csv`.

I ran the code in Visual Studio 2017 and VS Code with the same results.

Update #1 - I placed a breakpoint on `CsvFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync()`. The breakpoint gets hit when requesting a single resource. The breakpoint does not get hit when requesting the collection.

Here is startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{       
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
      options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
      options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/xml"));
      options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("json", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/json"));
      options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("csv", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv"));
      options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CsvFormatter());
    })
      .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
  }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
  {
    app.UseMvc();
  }
}
```

Here is the custom formatter:

```
public class CsvFormatter : TextOutputFormatter
{
  public CsvFormatter()
  {
    SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv"));
    SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
    SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
  }

  protected override bool CanWriteType(System.Type type)
  {
    return type == typeof(TodoItem);
  }

  public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
  {
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    if (context.Object is IEnumerable<TodoItem>)
    {
      foreach(var todoItem in (IEnumerable<TodoItem>)context.Object)
      {
        FormatCsv(buffer, todoItem);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      FormatCsv(buffer, (TodoItem)context.Object);
    }
    using (var writer = context.WriterFactory(response.Body, selectedEncoding))
    {
      return writer.WriteAsync(buffer.ToString());
    }
  }

  private static void FormatCsv(StringBuilder buffer, TodoItem item)
  {
    buffer.AppendLine($"{item.Id},\"{item.Name}\",{item.IsComplete}");
  }
}
```

Comment: return type == typeof(TodoItem) ||  typeof(IEnumerable<TodoItem>)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected override bool CanWriteType(System.Type type)
{
    return type == typeof(TodoItem);
}
```

Obviously, this makes your formatter only run when an entity of type `TodoItem` is being returned. If you want your formatter to only run for collections of `TodoItem`, you will have to check that here.

Depending on what type of collection you are returning, you will have to make sure that the check returns `true` for that. One way would be to check whether the type is assignable to `IEnumerable<TodoItem>`:

```
return typeof(TodoItem).IsAssignableFrom(type) ||
    typeof(IEnumerable<TodoItem>).IsAssignableFrom(type);
```

That way, you can return arrays, lists, and any other type of enumerable.

---

Btw. looking at your implementation, is there a reason why you are using a `StringBuilder` as a buffer? You could just write to the output stream directly.

Comment: As to the use of `StringBuilder`, I'm not the author of the original code. I found the code while researching how to address some content negotiation questions. Thanks for the suggestion and I'll look at that in my own implementation.